# Python C-API: Using `PySequence_Length` with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-c-api

I'm trying to use `PySequence_Length` to get the length of a Python dictionary in C.  I realize I can use `PyDict_Size`, but I'm interested in using a more generic function in certain contexts.

```
PyObject* d = PyDict_New();
Py_ssize_t res = PySequence_Length(d);

printf("Result : %ld\n", res);
if (res == -1) PyErr_Print();
```

This fails, and prints the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'dict' has no len()

My question is: why does this fail?  Although Python dictionary objects don't support the Sequence protocol, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/sequence.html?highlight=pysequence_length#PySequence_Length) for `PySequence_Length` says:

> Py_ssize_t PySequence_Length(PyObject *o)
>
> Returns the number of objects in sequence o on success, and -1 on
>   failure. For objects that do not provide sequence protocol, this is
>   equivalent to the Python expression len(o).

Since a dictionary type does have a `__len__` attribute, and since the expression `len(d)` (where `d` is a dictionary) properly returns the length in Python, I don't understand why `PySequence_Length` should fail in C.

Any explanation?  Is the documentation incorrect here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is misleading, yes. A dict is not a sequence, even though it does implement some parts of the sequence protocol (for containment tests, which are part of the sequence protocol.) This particular distinction in the Python/C types API is unfortunate, but it's an artifact of a design choice made decades ago. The documentation reflects that distinction, albeit in an equally awkward way. What it tries to say is that *for Python classes* it's the same thing as `len(o)`, regardless of what the Python class pretends to be. For C types, if the type does not implement the sequence version of the sizefunc, `PySequence_Length()` will raise an exception without even considering whether the type has the mapping version of the sizefunc.

If you are not entirely sure whether you have a sequence or not, you should use `PyObject_Size()` instead. In fact, there's very little reason to call `PySequence_Length()`; normally you either know the type (because you just created it, and you can call a type-specific length function or macro like `PyList_GET_SIZE()`) or you don't even know if it'll be a sequence.